# Phonegap Accelerometer Sample Rate

Tags: cordova, accelerometer

Hi im building a Phonegap App using Accelerometer Data.
Right now im getting a sample rate of like 14 Hz, which seems to be  very little, since im trying to classify movement data.

With a sensor speed test tool i saw that the speed i have is somehow similiar to the sensor rate SENSOR_DELAY_UI which is a setting that can be picked when registering the sensor. When i change it in the test app to SENSOR_RATE_FASTEST i get around 100Hz.

But how can i set this up from a Phonegap APP?

```
function startstoptracking(){
         if(sensorAcc == null) {
             $('#button').html('Stop');
             createWriter();
             var options = { frequency: 40 };
             sensorAcc =      navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(accelerometerSuccess,accelerometerError, options);
         } else {
            navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(sensorAcc);
            sensorAcc = null;
             $('#button').html('Start');
         }
    }
```

Im happy about any help...

Comment: The frequency elements just seems to change how often the accelerometer is called. but not how often it changes its value. If i change frequency to faster number i get only duplicates... but never more data then 14 samples a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not possible that times in phonegap to set a faster rate.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your application in Phonegap you can setup frequency of acceleration (in miliseconds) by options:

example:

```
function startYourApplication() {
    var options = { frequency = 8000 };
}
```

Link to solution: 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#accelerometerOptions

Comment: I habe frequency allready at40 and also tried other values. No change. The Sensor gets registered AS ui.